# Run only tests which depend on the change

Tags: python, testing, pytest

How to detect which tests pytest need to run?

Up to now I run all tests in CI. This is slow.

Isn't there a way to automatically detect which tests need to run, and only execute a fraction of the whole test suite?

Background: I am reading the Google SE book and read about their gigantic monorepo and that their tool Blaze can detect which tests need to run. Sounds very cool.

Comment: I guess you're looking for [`pytest-testmon`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-testmon/), which determines the subset of tests to execute based on coverage (so having a 100% line/branch coverage is highly recommended). You can also switch to Bazel for building and testing and use the `py_test` rule, but IIRC Bazel needs an explicit source mapping for incremental tests to work, which can be tedious to maintain.

Comment: @hoefling please write your comment as answer. Then I can up-vote it. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had good experience with [`pytest-testmon`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-testmon/) which determines the subset of tests to execute on code change based on test coverage. The details on that are explained well in [Determining affected tests](https://testmon.org/blog/determining-affected-tests/) section of `testmon`'s docs, but the general advice is to maintain high line/branch coverage for `testmon` to be effective. This also means that it will fail where `coverage` fails.

If you want to use it in the CI, you need to cache the `.testmondata` database file between test jobs and ensure the `--testmon` arg is used when invoking `pytest`. It also depends on your CI provider, but most popular ones out there offer caching mechanisms (Github, Gitlab, CircleCI, Appveyor etc).

`testmon` can also be effectively combined with [`pytest-watch`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-watch/) watchdog to keep a daemon for test execution running. An example command that reruns subset of tests on code changes and sends system notifications on success or failure:

```
$ pytest-watch --runner="pytest --testmon" \
  --onfail="notify-send --urgency=low -i error 'Tests Failed'" \
  --onpass="notify-send --urgency=low -i info 'Tests passed'"
```

You can also use Bazel for building and testing as well; however, IMO it is an overkill for a pure Python project and is not worth it for just the incremental testing purposes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the pytest-incremental plugin for this which uses AST to analyse the import structure of a project and only runs tests for which the source code has changed.

```
pip install pytest-incremental
python -m pytest --inc
```

[image]

> Analyzing the graph is easy to see that a change in app would cause
> only test_app to be execute. And a change in util would cause all
> tests to be executed.

[from the docs](https://pytest-incremental.readthedocs.io/runner.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can add `@pytest.mark` to the tests

```
@pytest.mark.SomeFeature
@pytest.mark.Regression
def test_example1(self):
    pass

@pytest.mark.AnotherFeature
@pytest.mark.Regression
def test_example2(self):
    pass
```

And use it when triggering the tests

```
pytest TestsFolder -m SomeFeature
```

This will run only `test_example1`, `-m Regression` will run both tests.

Comment: I am looking for an automated way to detect which tests need to run.